# Gnuplot label points off values

Tags: gnuplot

I have numbers which are sometimes much more higher than others, there are peaks. To avoid "zeroing" all others numbers which are not readable, I set max for y.

But how to show labels for points, which are over 2000? To show for example text 65392(original y) near peak ended at 2000. How to do it?

```
f(y) = y > 2000 ? 2000 : (y < -2000 ? -2000 : y)
using 1:(f(\$3)) notitle with line lw 3
```

fla(y)= y > 500 ? sprintf("%.0f", y) : (y < -500 ? sprintf("%.0f", y) : 1/0)
using 1:(f($3)) notitle with line lw 3 
using 1:(abs($3)>499 ? $3 : 1/0):(fla($3)) notitle with labels offset character 0, character 1 tc rgb "blue" right

[trying with label for peaks above 500(or lower -500)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDimz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example which creates some random test data.
It uses the ternary operator (check `help ternary`) to select the actual value plotted as well as a label and a symbol (triangle up or down) via variable pointtype if the value is above/below the threshold `+/-ymax`.

- labels are placed at `+/-ymax*1.15`, i.e. 15% offset from the limit `+/-ymax`.

**Script:**

```
### limit range with labels for peaks outside range
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    plot '+' u 1:(rand(0)*4000-2000 + int(rand(0)+0.03)*(rand(0)*120000-60000)) w table
unset table

set key noautotitle

set multiplot layout 2,1

    plot $Data u 1:2 w l lc "red" ti "original data"
    
    ymax = 2000
    outOfRange(col) = abs(column(col)) > ymax
    limit(col)      = (y=column(col), abs(y)<=ymax ? y : sgn(y)*ymax)
    set yrange[-ymax*1.5:ymax*1.5]
    plot $Data u 1:(limit(2)) w l lc "blue" ti "limited data", \
            '' u 1:(outOfRange(2) ? limit(2) : NaN):(y>0?9:11) w p pt var lw 4 lc "red", \
            '' u 1:(outOfRange(2) ? limit(2)*1.15 : NaN):(sprintf("%.0f",column(2))) w labels offset 0,0, \
         ymax dt 2 lc "black", \
        -ymax dt 2 lc "black"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @Pragmas if this solved your problem, please check the check mark at the top left of the answer, indicating that the question is answered.